# Alternate for max() function in db2

Tags: sql, db2, max

I am executing a complex query in DB2 and the response time of which is quite high. After a lot of R&D, I found that the repetitive use of the `max()` function is causing hindrance in the execution time.
Thus I wish to know if there is an alternative for the `max()` function. I read a bit about `rank()` and was wondering if the same could be used, but wasn't able to get the result I wanted.

A part of my query is:

```
   Select DISTINCT
   (Select MAX(DATE(last_timestamp)) from Table_1 where ID = E.EID)
   From Table_2 E
```

I am stuck at this for too long now. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What indexes exist for your table? Did you study the access-plan for your query? Are your runstats up to date and appropriate? Your query seems simple, but without the access-plan (from db2exfmt if your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows) we can't help much. You probably don't need an alternative MAX(), but instead you may need better indexes or statistics or selectivity.

Comment: I guess distinct clause causing query to run for long time, not `max` and you haven't used `group by` with anything else, it will return only one row, why do u need distinct

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?  You want the max date (last_timestamp) for each EID?  but no duplicate dates regardless of EID?  I'm not a fan of having a select in a select as it has to execute for every record in table_2 in your example.  I'd rather join the two tables and then get the max.  1 query verses 1 for each record in table_2...

Comment: For speed max of timestamp is the first row of order by my_timestamp desc...fetching only the first row.

Answer (score 0):

row_number() is better than rank() since you don't want duplicates. Here it is. I'm thankful for this site as reference: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/finding_the_maximum_row_and_more56?lang=en

```
SELECT DISTINCT last_timestamp 
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.last_timestamp DESC) AS rn, DATE(A.last_timestamp) as last_timestamp
         FROM Table_1 A, From Table_2 E where A.ID = E.EID) 
  WHERE rn = 1;
```

The syntax might not be exact since I did not test it and I don't have DB2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be the conversion of the timestamp to a date - DATE() - before doing the MAX() function - not a DB2 expert, but would guess that this may end up creating a temp table of dates that is then MAXed, and indexes are not used...

Suggest that the following be tried:

```
Select DISTINCT
   DATE(
       Select MAX(last_timestamp) 
       from Table_1 
       where ID = E.EID
   )
From Table_2 E
```

Of course the query optimizer may be smart enough to do this...

Comment: what is the difference, extracting `max` from the column and converting into date, how many rows it will return do u reckon

Comment: (Unless the query optimizer does it) this will result in only one call of `DATE()`  for every `E.EID`, rather than calling `DATE()` on every `last_timestamp`. @Stavr00 answer should accomplish the same thing.

If there are about more than 1 `last_timestamp` per `EID`, this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can join on the following CTE :

```
WITH t1(i,t) AS 
( SELECT id, MAX(last_timestamp)
  FROM Table_1 
  GROUP BY id ) 
SELECT 
   ...
   DATE(t1.t),
   ... 
FROM Table_2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON Table_2.EID = t1.i
```